# I want to create a condition from the option tag, for example if I select green, it will show 5 images, but display it using the for/do while tag?

Tags: php, for-loop, html-select

```
<select name="operator">
    <option name="green">green</option>
    <option name="purple">purple</option>
    <option name="orange">Orange</option>
</select><p></p><br>
<button type = "submit">Check</button>


for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++) {
    echo "<img src = ""
}
```

Comment: Well then you are going to have to check what is selected before running the loop

Comment: Could of course take a quick squint at the [HTML spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) and check what attributes are legal in an `<option>` tag. **hint** `name` is not a valid attribute

Comment: You could use the option (correctly) and have the counter in the value attribute like `<option value="5">green</option>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select name="operator">
    <option value="green">green</option>
    <option value="purple">purple</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
</select><p></p><br>
<button type = "submit">Check</button>

if($request->operator == 'green') {
    for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++) {
        echo "<img src = "" 
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please add a small description for each code block?

Comment: thankyou!!! sometimes i know how it should work, but i don't know how i should write the code to make it valid

Comment: This rather assumes a framework, which was not mentioned anywhere in the question

Comment: correction for if tag : if($_REQUEST ['operator'] == 'green')